# 1265 Error - Data Truncated for transfer of Date value to table

Tags: python, sql

Question: I do not understand how to resolve this error.  My hypothesis from reviewing other questions is that I have a column violation either passing the wrong data type or a null value.  Alas, I cannot find the appropriate solution to the error.  Any guidance or help appreciated.

Error code: mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'date' at row 1

Code where I think the error lies:

```
#add record to database
def add_record():

sql_command = "INSERT INTO money (date, account_name, account_type, amount) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
values = (date_box.get(), account_name_box.get(), account_type_box.get(), amount_box.get())
my_cursor.execute(sql_command, values)

#commit the changes
mydb.commit()
#clear the fields
clear_data()

#delete date/time or insert date/time
def date_time_insert():
date_box.delete(0, END)
date_box.insert(0, datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Question added to body, appreciate any guidance

Comment: Generally, data truncation errors come from Database in case that you are trying to insert data to a column which is more than its size defined on Database. Issue you have looks is about column **date**, is **date** column's type is `DATE` on Database or it is a `VARCHAR`? And database you are using is it MS SQL or My SQL?